# Is there a limit to number of calls to Twitter Search API?

Tags: api, twitter, twitter4j

I am working on a study of social media during the 2016 campaign. We would like to leverage Twitter's Search API to get the bulk of our data.

We believe there will be over 100 millions tweets with the keywords and would like to create a script to make the API call and store the information. If we follow Twitter's rate limits of 450 requests per 15 minutes, will Twitter limit the number of queries we submit from our API key? Would it be possible to use [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) and obtain **ALL** tweets and related data posted during 2016 that have the words *Hillary* and *Trump*?

Answer (score 1):

> If we follow Twitter's rate limits of 450 requests per 15
>   minutes, will Twitter limit the number of queries we submit from our
>   API key?

No, Twitter will not limit you if you follow the rate limits. With Twitter4j, you could ask Twitter how many queries you have left.

> Would it be possible to use GET search/tweets and obtain ALL
>   tweets and related data posted during 2016 that have the words Hillary
>   and Trump?

No, it won't be possible. As the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) states:

> The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.

So, you can only get recent tweets from the search API. Be careful too with the data beacuse it's about relevance not completeness, from the same documentation:

> Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead.

If you really need older tweets you will have to get them from other sources like [Gnip](https://gnip.com/) (you need to pay). Otherwise you will have to approach differently your problem.

If you have the names (or id's) of all the users that you want to get info you could get the [timelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943161/get-tweets-of-a-public-twitter-profile) from each user getting up to 3200 tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Twitter will limit the number of queries submitted from your API key.  It would be very difficult to obtain ALL of the tweets you are seeking to obtain.

> Rate limiting of the API is primarily on a per-user basis — or more
>   accurately described, per user access token. If a method allows for 15
>   requests per rate limit window, then it allows 15 requests per window
>   per access token.
>
> When using application-only authentication, rate limits are determined
>   globally for the entire application. If a method allows for 15
>   requests per rate limit window, then it allows you to make 15 requests
>   per window — on behalf of your application. This limit is considered
>   completely separately from per-user limits.
>
> https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting

Look into using their Streaming API.

Comment: According to my calculations of Twitter's rate limits it will take around 25 hours to obtain 100 million tweets using the Search API. How many calls would Twitter allow if I comply with the rate limit of 15 requests per window? I need historical tweets, I assume the Streaming API is for new tweets. Am I correct?

Comment: I could not find any information on whether the Streaming API is for new tweets or not, sorry.  There are two initial buckets available for GET requests: 15 calls every 15 minutes, and 180 calls every 15 minutes.  Does the above answer your initial question?