# get tweets by particular user using twitter4j java api

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to get tweets by particular user by entering its `userId`.

I can search for a text by:

```
     Query query = new Query("Hi");
        QueryResult result;
        do {
            result = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
            for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + 
                     " - " + tweet.getText());
                }
            } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
```

but how can I search for the tweets by entering particular `userId`, is there any direct method or I have to apply logic ?

I am trying:

```
            Status status = twitter.showStatus(id);
            if (status != null){
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName()
                + " - " + status.getText());}
```

where id is userId, but by doing this, I am getting the error:

> Failed to search tweets: 404:The URI requested is invalid or the
>   resource requested, such as a user, does not exists. Also returned
>   when the requested format is not supported by the requested method.
>   message - No status found with that ID. code - 144

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Twitter API you can get up to ~3200 tweets from an user, to do this you can get the time line from an specific user, see those questions

- [Get tweets of a public twitter profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943161/get-tweets-of-a-public-twitter-profile)
- [Twitter4J: Get all statuses from Twitter account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449724/twitter4j-get-all-statuses-from-twitter-account)

By the way, you are getting that error because you are using `twitter.showStatus(id);` with an `userid`, you need to call `twitter.showUser(id)` and you won't get that error

Comment: so does that means that if i want all the tweets from a user which is more than 3200 , i cant get it?

Comment: No, if you want all the tweets from an user who has more than 3200 you will need another source (like Topsy, but I don't know how to use it)

Comment: Is there a way to verify if a given userid is valid - not mine who is using this, but some other twitter user I may want to specify to get their tweets.